# How can i List any actors

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, mysql-workbench

I’m trying to list the actors (male/female) that have starred in 10 or more different film genres I have a table called **actors** which contains three columns:`actorID`,`name`,`gender` and another table called **movies** which contains `movieID`,`title`,`year`, last table is **movies_actor** it contains `movieID`,`actorID`,`as_charachter`,`leading`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the count of movie for each actor You need the actor_name and the movieid which are in two different table. First you can take the actorid and the count of movieid from movies_actors table and the join it with the actor_table to get the name of the actor. You have to apply a condition in select statement >9 as you want the actor name who has done 10 or more than 10 movies. For genres you can try once from your end if you get any error then you can ask question.

```
     select name from  
       (select s.*,a.name from 
          (select actorid, count(distinct movieid)no_of_movies from movies_actors group by  actorid)s 
      join 
      actor_table a
      on a.actorid=s.actorid
       )b
where no_of_movies>9
```

But It will be good for you if you try first from your end and then you can ask questions here like if you stuck or if you get any error or not get the desired output. In this way you can learn more.

Comment: its not working

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'count(distinct movieid)no_of_movies from imdb_movies2actors group by  actorid)s ' at line 3

Comment: Hi Can you retry. There was a comma missing. I have added

Comment: thanks but can you explain the code please

Comment: also the question was List any actors (male/female) that have starred in 10 or more different film genres.

Comment: i forget to add one more table i will edit above can you re check ?

Comment: I have added the description. But please try from your end once for genres.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether below query give your expected result.

```
SELECT
  a.name,
  a.gender,
  COUNT(ac.movieid) NoOf_Movies
FROM
  actors a
  INNER JOIN actor_movie am ON a.id = am.actorID
GROUP BY
  a.name,
  a.gender
HAVING
  COUNT(ac.movieid) > 9
ORDER BY
  am.movieID DESC
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: is there any error message ? or is this query don't give any output?

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ac.movieid' in 'field list'

Comment: it gives this error

Comment: Please check whether table name and column names are correct. In your previous query your table name was actor_movie but in the question your table name is movies_actor. So replace the correct table names and column names and try again

Comment: even tho the tables are correct am getting this :  Unknown column 'ac.movieid' in 'field list'

Comment: the problem, is in ac.movieid not sure why

Comment: Well there is no `ac` table in the `FROM` clause. I assume it needs to be `am.movieid`.

Comment: can you edit ur code please

Comment: what is a.id  thats the error that am getting now

Comment: i dont know man your query is not working :(

Comment: Can I have your tables names and column names please? Then I will modify the query according to that

Comment: i have a table called actors which contains three columns:actorID,name,gender and another table called movies which contains movieID,title,year, last table is movies_actor it contains movieID,actorID,as_charachter,leading
and another table called movie director which had movieid directorid and genre

Comment: I’m trying to list the actors (male/female) that have starred in 10 or more different film genres , and here is what am trying to do